# Evaluate the indefinite trigonometric double angle integral

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, substitution

The integral is $$\int \csc(2x)dx$$
I have tried transforming  it into 
$$\int \frac{1}{\sin(2x)}dx $$
then using u-sub. I get 
$$u=\sin(2x)$$
$$du=2\cos(2x)$$
but I have trouble getting $du=1$, because then I can take the $\ln(u)$

I then thought of using one of $\cos(2x)$'s double angle formulas but still nothing.

To help get the proper solution, I looked up the answer in the back of the book and its 
$$-\frac{1}{2} \ln\mid\csc(2x)+\cot(2x)\mid+C$$

Comment: Make a substitution $u = 2x => du / 2 = dx$. What converts your integral into $\int \csc(u)/2du$. The integral of csc (u) can be easily found in tables of integrals.

Comment: That method yields $\frac{1}{2} \ln(\tan(x))+C$, and when I looked at the answer it contained a csc and cot

Comment: Both answers are correct.  Differentiate them, get $\csc(2x)$.  Check that your answer and the book answer are equal (possibly up to a constant addend).

Comment: The GEdgar is correct. Probably the answer of the book manipulated the above using the properties of logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int \csc(2x)dx=\int \sec\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2x\right)dx$$
Now, taking $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-2x$ we get 
$$-\frac{1}{2} \int \sec(u)du$$
and recall that, this is equal to
$$-\frac{1}{2} \log \big| \sec(u)+\tan(u)\big|+c$$
Returning the variables
$$-\frac{1}{2} \log \left| \sec\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2x\right)+\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2x\right)\right|+c=-\frac{1}{2}\log \big|\csc(2x)+\cot(2x)\big|+c$$

Comment: Is that log meant to be the natural log?

Comment: Yes, it is: $\log=\ln$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \csc(2x)dx=\int \frac{1}{\sin(2x)}dx=\int \frac{1}{2\sin(x) \cos(x)}dx=$$

$$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{2\sin^2(x) \cos(x)}dx=$$

$$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{2(1-\cos^2(x)) \cos(x)}dx$$

The substitution $u=\cos(x)$, $du=-\sin(x)dx$ changes the integral into

$$\int \frac{du}{2u(u^2-1)}$$

which is solved by partial fractions.

Answer (score 0):

As,

> $$\int\csc(ax)dx = - \frac{1}{a}\ln|\csc(ax)+\cot(ax)|+c$$

$$\color{green}{\int\csc(2x)dx = - \frac{1}{2}\ln|\csc(2x)+\cot(2x)|+c}$$

---

---

If you need a proof for the above formula,

$$\int\csc(ax)dx = \int\frac{\csc(ax)\big[\csc(ax)+\cot(ax)\big]dx}{\csc(ax)+\cot(ax)}$$

Let $$t= \csc(ax)+\cot(ax)\implies dt = -\bigg[a\csc(ax)\cot(ax)+a\csc^2(ax)\bigg]dx $$
$$\csc(ax)[\csc(ax)+\cot(ax)\big]dx = \frac{-dt}{a}$$

So, $$\color{blue}{\int\csc(ax)dx = -\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{dt}{t} = -\frac{1}{a}\ln|t| +c= -\frac{1}{a}\ln|\csc(ax)+\cot(ax)|+c}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here we will address the integral:
\begin{equation}
I = \int \csc(2x)\:dx
\end{equation}
First let $u = 2x$:
\begin{equation}
I = \int \csc(u)\cdot \frac{1}{2}\:du = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{\sin(u)}\:du
\end{equation}
We now employ the Weirerstrauss Substitution $t = \tan\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)$:
\begin{equation}
I =\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{\frac{2t}{1 + t^2}} \cdot \frac{2}{1 + t^2}\:dt = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{t}\:dt = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left| t\right| + C = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\tan\left(\frac{u}{2}\right) \right| + C = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\tan\left(x \right) \right| + C
\end{equation} 
Where $C$ is the constant of integration.